# vtk tcl wrapping

Tags: linker, tcl, tk-toolkit, vtk

I'm trying to build VTK with  VTK_WRAP_TCL=ON and  VTK_USE_TK=ON but having following linker errors:

```
> Compiling...
vtkTkAppInit.cxx
Compiling resources...
Microsoft (R) Windows (R) Resource Compiler Version 6.0.5724.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
Compiling manifest to resources...
Microsoft (R) Windows (R) Resource Compiler Version 6.0.5724.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
Linking...
   Creating library D:\VTK\bin\bin\Debug\vtk.lib and object D:\VTK\bin\bin\Debug\vtk.exp
vtkTkAppInit.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__Tk_MainEx referenced in function _main
vtkTkAppInit.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__Tcl_CreateInterp referenced in function _main
vtkCommonTCL.lib(vtkTclUtil.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__Tcl_CreateInterp
vtkTkAppInit.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__Tcl_SetVar referenced in function _Tcl_AppInit
vtkCommonTCL.lib(vtkTclUtil.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__Tcl_SetVar
vtkTkAppInit.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__Tcl_Eval referenced in function _Tcl_AppInit
vtkTkAppInit.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__Tk_Init referenced in function _Tcl_AppInit
vtkTkAppInit.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__Tcl_Init referenced in function _Tcl_AppInit
vtkCommonTCL.lib(vtkTclUtil.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__Tcl_GetAssocData referenced in function "struct vtkTclInterpStruct * __cdecl vtkGetInterpStruct(struct Tcl_Interp *)" (?vtkGetInterpStruct@@YAPAUvtkTclInterpStruct@@PAUTcl_Interp@@@Z)
vtkFilteringTCL.lib(vtkSourceTcl.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__Tcl_DeleteCommand referenced in function "int __cdecl vtkSourceCppCommand(class vtkSource *,struct Tcl_Interp *,int,char * * const)" (?vtkSourceCppCommand@@YAHPAVvtkSource@@PAUTcl_Interp@@HQAPAD@Z)
vtkRenderingTCL.lib(vtkAbstractVolumeMapperTcl.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__Tcl_DeleteCommand
vtkRenderingTCL.lib(vtkImporterTcl.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__Tcl_DeleteCommand
vtkWidgetsTCL.lib(vtkContinuousValueWidgetRepresentationTcl.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__Tcl_DeleteCommand
vtkFilteringTCL.lib(vtkProcessObjectTcl.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__Tcl_DeleteCommand
vtkFilteringTCL.lib(vtkMapper2DTcl.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__Tcl_DeleteCommand
vtkFilteringTCL.lib(vtkViewportTcl.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__Tcl_DeleteCommand
vtkFilteringTCL.lib(vtkAbstractMapperTcl.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__Tcl_DeleteCommand
vtkFilteringTCL.lib(vtkThreadedImageAlgorithmTcl.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__Tcl_DeleteCommand
vtkFilteringTCL.lib(vtkImageInPlaceFilterTcl.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__Tcl_DeleteCommand
vtkFilteringTCL.lib(vtkRectilinearGridSourceTcl.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__Tcl_DeleteCommand
.
.
D:\VTK\bin\bin\Debug\vtk.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 65 unresolved externals
Results

Build log was saved at "file://d:\VTK\bin\Wrapping\Tcl\vtk.dir\Debug\BuildLog.htm"
vtk - 22432 error(s), 0 warning(s)
```

Please help to solve.
Thanks.

Comment: Immediate diagnosis: it's not actually linking against either the Tcl nor the Tk libraries (or maybe the import libraries; I'm less familiar with the details of building programs on Windows than for Unix). No idea why this is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed Tclx64 version and was trying to build it with 32 bit compiler.
Problem is solved by installing x86 version and compiled it with Debug|Win32.

http://public.kitware.com/pipermail/vtkusers/2011-September/118696.html this post helped me to understand the problem.